# How to create optional field in regex validation (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using https://www.debuggex.com/ to debug my regex and it looks like `^(\+?\d{2})\d{8}$` - it's supposed to check if phone number is `+1212345678`(#1) and it should also be ok if it was `+12 12345678`(#2) or just `12345678`(#3), but the only valid expression is #1 - what should I adjust to make it accept those 2 patterns as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fixed regex:

```
^(\+?\d{2}\s*)?\d{8}$
          ^^^ ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK9iR5/1)

I made the first capturing group optional with `?`, and added optional whitespace `\s*`.